# Mirror Image but wrong size

Tags: python, image-processing, resize

I am trying to input an image (image1) and flip it horizontally and then save to a file (image2). This works but not the way I want it to

currently this code gives me a flipped image but it just shows the bottom right quarter of the image, so it is the wrong size.  Am I overwriting something somewhere?  I just want the code to flip the image horizontally and show the whole picture flipped.  Where did I go wrong?

and I **cannot** just use a mirror function or reverse function, I need to write an algorithm

**I get the correct window size but the incorrect image size**

```
 def Flip(image1, image2):
    img = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(0, 0), image1)
    X, Y = img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()
    for y in range(Y):
        for x in range(X):
            r, g, b = img.getPixel(x,y)
            color = graphics.color_rgb(r, g, b)
            img.setPixel(X-x, y, color)
    win = graphics.GraphWin(img, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
    img.draw(win)
    img.save(image2)
```

Comment: Which image processing library are you using?

Comment: I am using the graphics imaging library

Comment: Never heard of it. Can you provide a URL?

Comment: Documentation is here Aya http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/index.html

Comment: thanks for finding that @Haz

Comment: it seems you are editing your source image. would it not be better to create a blank image and set those pixels instead? i think this code will create a mirror down the middle of the image of the right hand side. is this your desired effect?

Comment: my desired effect is to just flip the whole image horizontally, i want to see the same size of the original image just flipped across a vertical axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
win = graphics.GraphWin(img, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
```

The first argument to the GraphWin constructor is supposed to be the title, but you are instead giving it an Image object.  It makes me believe that maybe the width and height you are supplying are then being ignored.  The default width and height for GraphWin is 200 x 200, so depending on the size of your image, that may be why only part of it is being drawn.

Try something like this:

```
win = graphics.GraphWin("Flipping an Image", img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
```

Another problem is that your anchor point for the image is wrong.  According to the docs, the anchor point is where the center of the image will be rendered (thus at 0,0 you are only seeing the bottom right quadrant of the picture).  Here is a possible solution if you don't know what the size of the image is at the time of creation:

```
img = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(0, 0), image1)
img.move(img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2)
```

Comment: so I should just change img to another variable name?

Comment: Yes, try giving it a string for the title of the window that GraphWin creates.

Comment: I tried that and it keeps giving me errors that the name I gave it is not defined and the only one that I can see working is `img` so what do you suggest I change `img` to?

Comment: I did not try the string method you suggested, i posted the last comment before I read your comment.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I don't, what exactly are you saying to put in there instead of `img`

Comment: I tried that and still the same error where it just shows me a quarter of the flipped image

Comment: the image is the wrong size but the window is the correct size...so i get the bottom quarter of the image flipped and then in the window that flipped image is in the upper left hand corner

Comment: Your anchor point is wrong.  I've updated my answer with a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are editing your source image. It would be
better to create an image copy and set those pixels instead:

create a new image for editing:

```
img_new = img
```

Assign the pixel values to that:

```
img_new.setPixel(X-x, y, color)
```

And draw that instead:

```
win = graphics.GraphWin(img_new, img_new.getWidth(), img_new.getHeight())
img_new.draw(win)
img_new.save(image2)
```

This will also check that your ranges are correct.  if they are not, you will see both flipped and unflipped portions in the final image, showing which portions are outside of your ranges.

Comment: would I put `img_new = img` right after `img = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(0, 0), image1)` ? or somewhere else?

Comment: cah, the new image line should go after the move command @haz has suggested.  They have made some good points.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using an external library, I'd recommend the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  In particular, the `ImageOps` module has a `mirror` function that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: good idea, but I can't just use a function like that, I would like to but I have to write out an algorithm for this